# git diff --name-only with no file paths

Tags: git, git-diff

How do I execute the following command getting filenames without paths?

So, literally, what the command says, "name-only" - not the file paths, just the file names.

```
git diff --name-only <commit> <commit>
```

Comment: you can always `for i in \`git diff --name-only <commit> <commit>\` ; do basename $i ; done`

Comment: What if you have two different `README.txt` files in different subdirectories? Why do you want to ignore the paths?

Comment: Then I'd like it to only show the `README.txt` file once. From my comment below, "My manager is content with the file paths included, I assumed he didn't want them, so I panicked and made this question"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK this is not provided by git since this is a pretty unusual requirement. For example my first try in my repository yielded about a dozen lines, each saying `pom.xml` because I just created a new version.

---

You can use a small script though. `basename` is your friend here.

I like `xargs` so I'd do it like this

```
git diff --name-only <commit> <commit> | xargs -n1 basename
```

This will fail if `git diff` provides no output.

Or for a loopy version

```
for s in `git diff --name-only <commit> <commit>` ; do basename $s ; done
```

Comment: Didn't work: basename: missing operand. Also, I can't use bash.

Comment: @Everlight, if you can't use bash what *can* you use? Pretty much any shell will let you do something like this. Are you on Windows without `basename`? You should probably add any such constraints to your question.

Comment: I'm using RHEL 5.7. So, anything within the Linux Terminal.

Comment: @Everlight If you used the first version, this means there was no output from `git diff`. This version also has no particular dependencies on bash.

Comment: By the first version, I assume you mean your first suggestion, which gave me the output, "basename: missing operand <new line> Try `basename --help' for more information." which repeated for each line in the output. So, there was output. If it has no dependency on bash then I assume its my version of basename: 5.97 is the problem.

Comment: @Everlight I have no RHEL at my disposal so I cannot really test this. It works with Ubuntu and I see no problem with RHEL's [version](http://www.flashnux.com/en/redhat/5/5.2/man1/basename.1.html). Do you have spaces in your paths?

Comment: No, but I think I'll be okay. My manager is content with the file paths included, I assumed he didn't want them, so I panicked and made this question.